# Free antivirus for Windows XP that runs silently

Tags: windows, gratis, antivirus

I'm looking for a free (gratis) antivirus program for Windows XP that runs silently.

By silently, I mean that I want a program that will automatically start, update itself, and scan without bothering the user unless something is detected.

I'm running Windows XP inside Windows 7's XP Mode (Windows Virtual PC).  I was using Microsoft Security Essentials, and up until the end-of-support day, it was working great.  Now Security Essentials is [anything but silent](https://superuser.com/q/738131/245988), nagging me several times to stop using XP every time I start up the virtual machine.

Required Features:

- Free (gratis)
- Runs on Windows XP
- Updates and protects with no user interaction, and does not bother the user for anything other than a positive detection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Avast](http://www.avast.com/index) will do this, set up appropriately. On my dad's system I turned off the audio-prompts (which annoy the heck out of me) and set it for silent/gaming mode (which prevents it launching popups). This should disable any inappropriate user interaction

Comment: Avast used to be a great antivirus, but now it continuously shows pop-ups advertising its products. This annoying behavior can be fixed blocking Internet connections of AvastUI.exe using your firewall.

Comment: As I've set it up, I hardly know its there. You *need* to turn off stuff manually for it to be truely silent, but its effective enough that this is the first I am hearing of ads

Comment: Ah sorry, I didn't try silent/gaming mode, so I guess you are right. But without it, just unchecking "Show additional recommendations" and "Show social networks" isn't enough to disable ads :(

Comment: I've not seen a single ad so far. Nor have I gotten any complaints about it.