# Gratis antivirus for Windows 7 x64 requiring little attention

Tags: gratis, windows-7, antivirus

I know that there is [similiar question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/4463/gratis-antivirus-software-accessible-by-screen-readers-without-pop-up-ads), but I'm unable to use Microsoft Security Essentials.

I have new PC with 8 GB of RAM and i7. It has freshly installed Windows 7 x64 and basics drivers.

**I wonder which antivirus install on it.**

I never used to use anything than Avast.

Two people which I trust told me to use something better than Avast.
When I asked what to use instead, they told me, but gave no or almost no explanation why software they recommend is good, so I decided to ask here.

What do you recommend **and why**?
Some hints about how to configure it the best way you know are also appreciated.

- It must be gratis.
- I'd like to it to require as little my attention as possible. Unneccesary pop-ups are not appreciated.

  - I don't adore pop-up ads, but I think that almost every gratis antivirus has it; they can be, unless they say something about feature which I don't know, when I click it does something for a while, ant *then* say that *I have to buy full version to access the feature*.
  - I don't want to know every success of the antivirus; I mean, I don't want to know when some basic stuff, like signature database update, went succesful.
  - I don't know much about personal computers security against malware, so it would be nice if the antivirus doesn't ask me about solutions of met problems, when it's sure what is the best for me. When it doesn't sure, if it has to ask, it would be nice if it would be able to suggest something.
- I don't like when antivirus scans every program wrote by me, when I want to launch it. At the moment I compile into few directories, so I think that possibility to exclude them from scanning would be enough.
- On my pendrive I have installed PortableApps platform and of course some portable apps. My pendrive gets connected to many computers; I want to be able to use my portable apps from pendrive on my PC without risk of infecting my PC (I'm affraid that my apps can get infected when pendrive gets connected to untrusted computer).
- If the software you recommend is Avast, tell me that - I don't say Avast is not good, other people told me that.

Comment: Related: [Free antivirus for Windows XP that runs silently](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/4550/free-antivirus-for-windows-xp-that-runs-silently)

Comment: @Greg Avast is only what you can recommend? If the question is a duplicate, where can I look for my question's answer?

Comment: I disagree with the question duplicate. You asked a good question, don't worry :)

Comment: Please elaborate on why you can't use Microsoft Security Essentials - whatever your issue with that, it may apply to other solutions, so knowing that issue would help get you a working solution.

Comment: @Michael: I'm almost sure that the problem occurs only with some of Microsoft's software. I don't want to share exact reason here.

Comment: Hey, Avast is good(I have been using it for more than 4 years) and you can customise it to work as you said in your question.

Comment: What exactly is wrong with MSSE? Some years back it was mediocre, but right now it's the only one I'll ever suggest to someone asking for a free AV, provided it's configured in a privacy-friendly fashion. Having worked in the AV industry (developing products _and_ working on an AV engine) I think I know a thing or two about AVs. And this whole A is better than B or C stuff is mostly hogwash. [No AV will protect you a 100% anyway.](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/36758/1609) And the AV tests are sometimes badly skewed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try [Panda Cloud Antivirus](http://download.cloudantivirus.com/). I have it installed on my parents' computer, and they never notice it's there.

Features:

- Gratis
- Requires no attention at all after the initial install

  - No pop-up ads. Although some features require the pro version, you won't be notified unless you actively click them
  - No pop-up success reports. You can view them when you open the app. Also no update reports. Since it works on the cloud, it's always up to date.
  - No technical decisions on your part. It automatically decides what to do
- I'm not sure if it can tell which programs you write, but you can add exceptions

I don't remember it requiring any special configuration. Just click through the setup and it should work well with default settings.

Comment: Seems interesting... but, what happens when temporarily I have no Internet connection and want to plug in pendrive, which was connected in untrusted place after last scan?

Comment: It does have a USB vaccination feature that protects you from viruses on USB disks even when offline. It also prevents these disks from being infected in the future. [Here](http://www.cloudantivirus.com/help/01/h_en/44.htm) are the instructions to turn it on

Comment: Seems nice, but I think that I didn't expressed precisely enough: I have a PortableApps platform on my pendrive, and I'd like to be able to use its apps on my PC without risk of getting malware into PC. How Panda deals with it?

Comment: @GingerPlusPlus I have not tested them together. My expectation is that it will remove the files that allow PortableApps to start automatically, but you will still be able to launch it normally by double clicking on the Start icon. It's better if you make a backup of your configuration files before testing it, just in case

Comment: I'm affraid that my apps can get infected.

Comment: @GingerPlusPlus I think I understand what you mean. It does offer [Behavioral Analysis Protection](http://www.cloudantivirus.com/en/forHome/) even in the free version. So it should be able to detect aggressive viruses on your pendrive apps even without internet

Comment: Thank you for your time and attention, I think I'll install the Panda in weekend, if I not find anything even better.