# Windows XP antivirus for AMD Sempron processor

Tags: gratis, antivirus, windows-xp

I'm looking for free AV software that runs under Windows XP on an AMD Sempron 3000+ (1,99 GHz) processor.

The machine was running [AVG](http://www.avg.com/) but that version expired, and the new one crashes on install, probably because it requires Intel SSE instructions.

Notes:

- I want only an AV on-access scanner, that PC probably can't handle a heavy full-security suite.
- [This question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/4550/free-antivirus-for-windows-xp-that-runs-silently) does not address the processor.
  The *no pop-up advertizing* requirement mentioned in there also applies in my case. It's for my 83 year old mother in law who cannot read English. I don't want her frightened by messages she cannot understand.

Comment: You might want to consider trying to pick up an old Win 7 system - obviously she doesn't need much in the way of computing power, and I'm sure you don't want to change anything if you can avoid it. But if you go to Win 7, you can just run the MS tool and you'll get security updates till 2020 or so.

Answer (score 1):

[ClamWinAV](http://www.clamwin.com/) at least still claims to run under Windows XP, Me, 2000, and 98. You'd have to test to see if it was OK with the processor, but the fact that it goes all the way back to 98 in it's support is a good hint that it might work out for you.

On the downside, it doesn't have an on-access scanner, but you could presumably set it up to run on a schedule and sweep the machine regularly. It wouldn't be as good as an on-access scanner like AVG, but it might be better than nothing.